# Enter Formula in cell with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to put a formula into my table.

I have an error 1004 on the line `cells(2,i).formulaR1C1` although I have recorded this formula that is working and put the same as recorded.

"CLEVES 1" to "CLEVES 5" are headers in the table. To test this code create a table with headers called CLEVES 1 to CLEVES 5.

[image]

```
Sub formula()

    Dim i As Long, ce As String

    For i = 1 To 10
        ce = CStr(Cells(1, i).Value)
        Cells(2, i).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(OR(MID([@[CLEVES 1]],1,2)=""" & ce & """,MID([@[CLEVES 2]],1,2)=""" & ce & """,MID([@[CLEVES 3]],1,2)=""" & ce & """,MID([@[CLEVES 4]],1,2)=""" & ce & """,MID([@[CLEVES 5]],1,2)=""" & ce & """),& ce &,"""")"
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Your are missing some `"` near the last ce

Comment: probably like: `... & ce & """)," & ce & ",""")"`

Comment: Great! It works Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set sheet name into the formula

> =IF(OR(MID([" & sheetName & "!@[CLEVES 1]],1,2)="""

For example.

I made table on Sheet2 and this worked ok:

```
 Sub formula()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ce As String
    Dim formulaString As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sheetName As String

    Set ws = Sheets("sheet2")

    sheetName = "Sheet2"

    For i = 7 To 17
            ce = CStr(Cells(1, i).Value)
            formulaString = Cells(2, i).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(OR(MID([" & sheetName & "!@[CLEVES 1]],1,2)=""" _
            & ce & """,MID([" & sheetName & "!@[CLEVES 2]],1,2)=""" & ce & """,MID([" & sheetName & "!@[CLEVES 3]],1,2)=""" _
            & ce & """,MID([" & sheetName & "!@[CLEVES 4]],1,2)=""" & ce & """,MID([" & sheetName & "!@[CLEVES 5]],1,2)=""" & ce & """),& ce &,"""")"
            ws.Cells(2, i).FormulaR1C1 = formulaString
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I am using Excel 2010 and it's French, I got the result "Faux" (False) on the cells.Do you have any ideas? Thank you

Comment: not sure, the formula must not be working. in all fairness this works now, you just have to fine tune the formula. if you add a screanshot the table and explain more what you want to do. but commentor above is probably right think u are missing an " gl

Comment: It is not working, how can I attach a screen shot?

Comment: edit ur original post and click on imgs button

Comment: Just added a picture to the question thanks